Two weighing scales compressed inside a solid frame
Two weighing scales are placed on top of each other at the bottom of a solid enclosed frame.
At the top of the frame a linear actuator is attached.
The linear actuator can extend and press down upon both of the scales together.

The linear actuator extends, applying a force which simulates a large weight applied to the scales. Both weighing scales are compressed by the actuator.
The scales are not identical in design, but they are both calibrated
(i.e. 10 kg mass shows the same reading on both scales independently, outside the frame)

Would both of the scales show the same measurement, just as they would for applying a weight on top of two scales on top of each other outside any frame?

Imagine the bottom weighing scale shows 10 kg. Does this mean that the force applied to both scales is equivalent to 10 kg of mass on the top scales, if the scales were outside the frame? Or does the presence of the outer frame complicate the forces involved?




Would both of the scales show the same measurement.

Assuming this is done on earth, then the mass of upper scale is supported by the lower scale.   The reverse is not true.   This represents a constant difference between the two.   You can imagine that if the actuator is removed, the upper scale should read zero, while the lower scale does not.
After accounting for that difference, then yes both would experience the same compressive force and would generate a reading representative of that force.
